# Play video from URL in new activity when finished loading

Tags: android, android-activity, video

Using the following code I can play a video on android in a new Activity. I would however like to preload the video (during a loading screen) and then show it when it is fully loaded. Is it possible to perhaps somehow trigger the activity to show later? In theory It would also be ok to not use a different activity.

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,OnPreparedListener
{

    private VideoView mVV;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);

        setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);

        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        if(url == null)
            finish();

        mVV = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        mVV.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mVV.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mVV.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
        mVV.start();
    }


    public void stopPlaying() {
        mVV.stopPlayback();
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }
}
```

from my main activity:

```
private void playVideo(String url) {
        Intent videoPlaybackActivity = new Intent(this, VideoPlayer.class);
        videoPlaybackActivity.putExtra("url", url);
        startActivity(videoPlaybackActivity);
    }
```

I presume I can use the onPrepared function, but I'm not sure how to do the activity triggering to show the activity later.

Comment: How about a fullscreen progress dialog that pops up when the activity starts and dismisses when the video is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.htmlHere are the methods for the VideoView. So there is indeed a:
setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener l)

Probably the best way is to use fragments in the activity and show the fragment in the activity where the mVV = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview); is declared when the onprepared is called.

Or hide and show the view in the activity. (using fragments is probably nicer).
Think that will work and that that is what you wanted?

Comment: I'd like to not have to go into fragments, My application is a single view game and this is just an exception for some introduction video. So I would like to show it similar to how video ads work. load (with a listener), show and hide again.

Comment: Setup a custom dialog in the activity with a video view in it. And call the dialog.show() in the OnPrepared? Then it will popup above the activity. I believe there are some examples on the internet to do that:).

Comment: That sounds like the way to go!